# Какой бы умный ты не/ни был

Tags: не-или-ни

Не найдётся ли какой-нибудь образованный человек, который подскажет каким правилом надо руководствоваться при выборе не/ни в следующем предложении:

> Какой бы ты умный не был, всегда найдётся кто-то умнее тебя.

Мне кажется, что правильно "не", хотя вот мне порекомендовали использовать "ни". Школьные правила я уже подзабыл, поэтому хочется разобраться в вопросе.

Comment: Лучше звучит, если поменять склонение: *Каким бы ты умным ни был, всегда найдётся кто-то умнее тебя.* И этот вариант более грамотный (литературный).

Comment: @oleedd Да у меня так и было, я просто взял из последней правки - а там уже "ты" подвинуто к "ни". Не могу сказать, что это какое-то осознанное употребление было (я и сейчас не вижу принципиальной разницы), просто так сказалось на автопилоте. А почему он более грамотный/литературный? Вроде как русский язык весьма гибкий к порядку членов предложения.

Comment: А я порядок слов вообще не менял, а только склонение (именительный падеж на творительный).

Comment: @oleedd Точно! Не заметил сразу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Частица "ни" употребляется перед сказуемым в придаточных предложениях для усиления утвердительного смысла**, например:
*Слушайтесь его во всем, что ни прикажет* (Пушкин).
*Не мог он ямба от хорея, как мы ни бились, отличить* (Пушкин).
*Куда ни оглянусь, повсюду рожь густая* (Майков).
*Кто ни проедет, всякий похвалит* (Пушкин).
Источник: http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/126-gl-19-13

*Какой бы ты умный **ни** был* — придаточное, подходит под правило.